# ExpressionBuilder.Expression(filters) in Kendo MVC grid not working for navigation collection

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, grid

We are using Kendo MVC Grid in our application. We are using LINQ to EF to query the tables.

Following is a query in our application:

```
query.Where(ExpressionBuilder.Expression<ParentTable>(command.Request.Filters))
```

This works fine as long as the filters are any columns from the "ParentTable". However, the ParentTable has a navigation collection `ICollection<ChildTable>` and the ChildTable has a property ChildProperty and the method ExpressionBuilder.Expression fails when we use this ChildProperty for filtering.

Any solution for this problem?

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: This has an [answer](http://www.telerik.com/forums/expressionbuilder-expression(filters)-in-kendo-mvc-grid-not-working-for-navigation-collection#ITFMcVWPSU2ff_RctEDgVA) given by Telerik support